# How to create a ticker chart using MPAndroidChart in android studio?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have and App which loads data from firebase, there is lot of data (double values) in the firebase database, so I am fetching this data and plot it on MPAndroidChart, it works well the data is plotting well with this sample code below:

```
 private void loadGraph() {
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sales");
        GraphView graph_petrol = ( GraphView ) findViewById (R.id.gragh_petrol1);
        mDatabase.child("JBC").orderByChild("totalpetrol").startAfter(null).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Double d_petrol = Double.valueOf(data.child("totalpetrol").getValue(Double.class));
                    Integer int_v = Integer.valueOf((int)Math.round(d_petrol));
                    TextView tvp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.d_append_petrol);
                    tvp.append(int_v + " " );
                    String strp = tvp.getText().toString().trim();

                    //get count of numbers
                    String[] wordsp=strp.split("\\s+");
                    System.out.println(wordsp.length);

                    //split string
                    List<Integer> numberListp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    for (String numberTextp : strp.trim().split("\\s+"))
                        numberListp.add(Integer.valueOf(numberTextp));
                    // To array
                    String[] numberTextsp = strp.trim().split("\\s+");
                    int[] numberArrayp = new int[numberTextsp.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberTextsp.length; i++)
                        numberArrayp[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberTextsp[i]);
                    // Show result
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numberArrayp)); // [2121, 23, 44, 55, 6, 58]

                    // form our data (curve) on X and Y
                    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> seriesPetrol = new LineGraphSeries < DataPoint > (); for (int i = 0; i < wordsp.length ; i ++) {
                        seriesPetrol.appendData ( new DataPoint( i , numberArrayp [ i ]), true , wordsp.length );
                    }

                    // Set the appearance of the
                    seriesPetrol.setTitle ( "ULP" ); // set the name of the curve for the legend
                    seriesPetrol.setDrawDataPoints ( true ); // draw points
                    seriesPetrol.setDataPointsRadius ( 5 ); // radius of the data point
                    seriesPetrol.setThickness ( 2 ); // line thickness
                    seriesPetrol.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

                    graph_petrol.addSeries (seriesPetrol);

                    //shade underthe graph
                    seriesPetrol.setDrawBackground(true);

                    // Graph petrol styling
                    graph_petrol . setTitle ( "ULP Sales Graph" );
                    graph_petrol . setTitleTextSize ( 20 );
                    graph_petrol . setTitleColor ( Color . WHITE ); // Legend
                    graph_petrol . getLegendRenderer (). setVisible ( false );
                    graph_petrol . getLegendRenderer (). setAlign (LegendRenderer. LegendAlign . TOP );
                    graph_petrol.getLegendRenderer().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    graph_petrol.getLegendRenderer().setTextSize(20);
                    graph_petrol.getLegendRenderer().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    // Axis captions petrol
                    GridLabelRenderer gridLabel_petrol = graph_petrol . getGridLabelRenderer ();
                    gridLabel_petrol.setHorizontalAxisTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
                    gridLabel_petrol.setVerticalAxisTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
                    gridLabel_petrol.setVerticalAxisTitleTextSize(15);
                    gridLabel_petrol.setHorizontalAxisTitleTextSize(15);
                    gridLabel_petrol.setHorizontalLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
                    gridLabel_petrol.setVerticalLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
                    gridLabel_petrol.setTextSize(20);

                    graph_petrol.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Error:  "+error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
}
```

What I want now is: avoid plotting all data at once, Lets say I have 20 double values in database, instead of plotting them once, I want them plotted one by one, each after another until the complete graph is plotted. In this case I mean for example: first value plots, second delays with one second, next delays with 1 second again one after another, sort of real time, (ticker).

So I want to put delays so that the graph actually plots in real time ticking each value after another until all data is plotted then it stops.

So my question is how can I achieve this with my current code above?

My grammer is not clear but um sure you will try to grasp my idea...

Comment: Hi! Have you tried adding your data using coroutine or Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {} (Kotlin)?  Maybe that could help

Comment: Can you help with sample code on that?

Comment: Hi @CoinChain! Sorry for not getting back earlier. Unfortunately, I don't have a sample code and this is just the idea I would try in your place. Please, read: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html I guess you need to add entry data inside of Timer or coroutine.